# javascript code for apache Cordova working on simulator Ripple but not in Live windows phone Device (L 535)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I wrote a just a test javascript code in index.js , it's an ordinary alert(), when ever I test in on ripple as android it works fine , when I test it on my Windows Phone its showing

```
Unhandled exception at line 16, column 13 in
ms-appx://io.cordova.myapp16ff10/www/scripts/index.js

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'alert' is undefined
```

**index.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

        document.getElementById("btnTakePhoto").onclick = function () {
            alert("button working fine!");
        };

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
} )();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <title>CameraDemoApp</title>

    <!-- CameraDemoApp references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello, world!</h2>

    <input id="btnTakePhoto" type="button" value="Take a Photo" />

    <p id="lastPhoto"></p>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

[Screenshot for Ripple (Android): it works fine!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6USI.png)

---

[Screenshot for Windows Phone (Lumia 535)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmOaK.png)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because there is no built-in support for `alert` in Windows Phone 7 and 8. Use PhoneGap's [Notification API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html) instead, and have something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.alert = window.alert || navigator.notification.alert;
    alert('button working fine!');
}
```